# How to code a library with a user defined parameter in C/C++?

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded

Is it possible to code a library with a parameter that will be defined by the user at compile time without modifying the library?

Library:

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#define MAX_NB USER_DEF

void myFunc(); 

#endif
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

int arr[MAX_NB] = {0}; 

void myFunc() {

    for (int i = 0: i < MAX_NB; i++ ) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }

}
```

And the main code:

```
#define USER_DEF 5
#include "test.h"

void main() {

    while (1) {
        myFunc(); 
    }

}
```

I suppose I am getting an error (USER_DEF not declared in this scope) because `USER_DEF` is not defined in the translation unit containing test.h and test.c, but I hope there is a way to do it, but I can't find it.

My goal is to have an array with a user-defined size (code modified).

Comment: Why don't you pass it as an argument to the function? A library should have a clear interface and not depend on some global state created by macros.

Comment: You can use compile flags (like `-DUSER_DEF=5`, if you really want to do it that way. This assumes that by library you mean source files that are distributed and meant to be compiled in (Arduino-style) as opposed to a compiled object or archive meant to be linked into the program, with header files used to interface with it.

Comment: @ryyker That's a very platform-specific way of doing things, and doesn't work in say, an embedded environment.

Comment: C or C++? They have very different answers to the question "how to declare a variable-sized array". Except in both languages you can of course use dynamic allocation as an option.

Comment: You can pass macro definitions on the command line, e.g. `-DNAME=value`.  People sometimes do this to control debugging for instance.

Comment: @Lundin Arduino environment uses C++, but I want a code that can be used later in other microcontrollers, that may or not have C++ compilers (e.g. PIC).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that it doesn't make sense to use variable-sized arrays for a very restricted 8-bit system with very limited RAM.

Instead you should have a fixed size array of *n* bytes. Let the user pick a number, then ensure that it is less or equal to *n*. Then keep track of the used size with a plain integer variable. You must always reserve memory for the worst case.

The array must have static storage duration, since it will be too large to be allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I'd usually go and suggest to check out the [templates](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/templates-cpp/), although, you can create user-defined variables, they are called function parameters. [Please take a look](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_functions.htm)
To sum it up, this is not what you call user-defined variable, because this is defined by the programmer, not by the user of the program. This is called a constant, whatsoever. If you want to create a compile-time constant, defined by you, you can take a look at [constexpr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr).

Also, let me explain to you why this doesn't work correctly. You guessed correctly, it's because it is not defined into the header file, but why? Because headers come first and then comes the main file. The header searches for the defined constant and fails to find it, and that is the reason why you get the `USER_DEF not declared in this scope`.

Comment: I want my code to be compatible with C. Thus, the array size must be defined at compile time (except if I use dynamic memory allocation).

Comment: Well, judging by the answer above, I'd suggest using dynamic memory allocation, since it will suit you best, or you can go for the `gcc -D USER_DEF=5 main.cc`. If you choose to go for the `D` flag, better protect it with something like
`#ifndef USER_DEF
#define USER_DEF 0
#endif`

Comment: @ardayigit When sticking to C++ checkout std::array